# About lifecycle hooks in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a higher order component as below. I have difficulty in understanding in which mounts first. See the below:

**MAIN COMPONENT (ADD EMPLOYEE)**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const AddEmployee = (props) => {

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("USE EFFECT");
    },[])

    return (//SOME JSX)
}

export default GlobalAxiosHandler(AddEmployee);
```

**HIGHER ORDER COMPONENT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const GlobalAxiosHandler = (WrappedComponent) => {

    return class extends Component {

        componentDidMount () {
            console.log('GLOBAL COMPONENTDIDMOUNT');
        }

     render() {

            console.log("RENDER GLOBAL");
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props}></WrappedComponent>
                </React.Fragment>)
        }
    }

}
```

The console output is as below

```
RENDER GLOBAL
GLOBAL COMPONENTDIDMOUNT
USE EFFECT
```

My question here is: Since wrapped component act as a child component to HOC, hence the componentDidMount() of HOC should get executed after useEffect() in the wrapped component. In such a case the output should've been like the below:

```
RENDER GLOBAL
USE EFFECT
GLOBAL COMPONENTDIDMOUNT
```

But the reverse happened. Can you please explain why. Hope I've articulated it properly.

**EDIT**: When I use the hooks in the HOC too as below (Using HOOKS both in HOC and Wrapped component):

```
import React, { useEffect, Component } from 'react';

const GlobalAxiosHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {

    const GlobalAxiosHandlerInner = (props) => {

        useEffect(()=>{
            console.log("USE EFFECT HOC");
        })

            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <WrappedComponent {...props}></WrappedComponent>
                </React.Fragment>)
    }

  return GlobalAxiosHandlerInner;
}

export default GlobalAxiosHandler;
```

I am seeing output as below (As I anticipated):

```
USE EFFECT WRAPPER  //(THIS IS FROM THE WRAPPED COMPONENT)
USE EFFECT HOC
```

Can you please explain why the reversal of life cycle events happening?

Comment: the parent didMount would fire before the child didMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` is equivalent to `componentDidMount` (also `didUpdate` and `willUnmount`) so it only gets called after the first render, that's exactly what's happening:

- `render` from HOC
- `render` form `WrappedComponent`
- `ComponentDidMount` from HOC
- `useEffect` from `WrappedComponent`

The console output should be:

```
RENDER GLOBAL
GLOBAL COMPONENTDIDMOUNT
USE EFFECT
```

Nothing wrong happening here

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. My query is child component's - componentDidMount() should execute first and at last parent component's componentDidMount() should execute. In this case HOC being acting as a parent here and it's componentDidMount() getting executed first and latter the wrapped component's

Comment: Nop. First the `first render` occurs on `Parent` and `Child`, then the `componentDidMount` on `Parent` followed by `useEffect` in `Child`

Comment: @METALHEAD react renders from top down, not bottom up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. One more query. Unlike above, if I use hooks in both HOC and wrapped component,  then useEffect() of wrapped component executing first and then the HOC. That's exactly reverse from what's happening above. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Now you got me. Could you post a snippet on code sandbox?

Comment: Just edited the question. Can you please look at it. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm getting off work now, when I'm home i'll analyze it!

Comment: Thank you so much man. I will wait for your reply. Have a great day ahead.

Comment: I'm on it. I'll try to reproduce this

Comment: Hi. I couldn't reproduce it... Can you post on codesandbox?

Comment: I build a generic version and runs fine.. Maybe is something specific to your code. sandbox would help us to see the same thing haha